# Change path of desktop

Tags: finder, macos, desktop

I would like to change the path that my desktop shows so instead of having a bunch of files that are in my desktop folder it shows the files in another folder. My desktop folder has files in it, so deleting that and symlinking the other folder won't work.

How can I change the folder the desktop displays?

Comment: It might be easier to just swap the content of `~/Desktop` and the other folder :-)

Comment: I want to change the folder the desktop is in relatively frequently, so having to move it every time would be annoying. This would also mean my current desktop folder isn't synced to icloud drive

Comment: -5 It has always been easier to put the moon on three astronauts instead of putting three astronauts on the moon... BTW that's the real reason why we only see one side of the moon: the backside is crowded with a googol of burnt out Saturn rocket stages and NASA doesn't want us to detect this.

Comment: @klanomath I’m trying to fill the space the desktop has with something useful to me, not sure what the problem is. Should it be worded as “replace desktop with custom folder” or something?

Comment: I can see what you're trying to achieve, but I don't know why you want to achieve it. Why not do as everybody else does & open your current work-in-progress folder. You can see it, you can access it simply from any file-picker dialog. If Apple's method of dragging the folder to the file-picker doesn't satisfy, then try [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html) which has several enhancements to accomplish this type of task.

Comment: @Tetsujin I wanted to try making the desktop useful

Comment: @pfg it is useful it shows some files on your screen background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder with the name *Desktop* in your user folder is a "blessed" folder. The content of this folder is shown on your GUI desktop.

To show the content of a different folder on your GUI desktop you'd have to rename the folder Desktop to an unused name and rename another folder to Desktop:

```
sudo mv ~/Desktop ~/myOldDesktop && sudo mv ~/myNewDesktop ~/Desktop
```

You may encounter graphical issues with the file and folder names on your "new" desktop afterwards.

It is not advisable to "enhance" another default user folder like *Pictures* or *Documents* like this.

---

If you have to organize your workflow (or your files and folders) like this, your workflow or your notion of the desktop metaphor is broken. That's like moving around work desks rather than files in an office.

Comment: I can do this with a symlink as well, but I guess it's not really possible to change the folder that shows on the desktop. I don't use my desktop and just wanted to see if there was a way I could make it show me my current project instead of being turned off

Comment: Adding another comment because I ran out of edit time. I don't want the metaphor of the desktop. That's why I want to replace it with quick access to my projects.