# I can't find Desktop folder in /Users/username

Tags: icloud, finder, desktop

I can't find the Desktop folder under /Users/username.

I'm not sure if it's a folder that doesn't originally exist.
Please see the picture below.
[image]

There is a Desktop item in the Favorites sidebar, but not on the right.
**I had previously turned off the Documents/Desktop checkbox in iCloud settings.**

Is it possible to recreate the Desktop folder on the right side?

Comment: What happens if you click on "Desktop" in the sidebar?

Comment: As of now, iCloud syncing is working normally. Obviously, items in Local's Desktop folder are synced to iCloud. Clicking on the Desktop folder in the sidebar will take me to the iCloud Drive > Desktop.

Comment: So you found your Desktop folder then (in iCloud Drive).

Answer (score 1):

You can find out where your Desktop folder is by

- clicking it (in the sidebar),
- then right-clicking into empty space in the resulting window,

[image: right-click menu in Finder within the desktop folder]

- then choosing "Get Info" and looking at the "Where" section:

[image: "Get Info" dialog in Mac Finder of the Desktop folder]

This will tell you where to find your Desktop folder.

Then, if you really want it to be shown in your user folder, you can symlink it using the terminal (Terminal.app) and entering this command to create a link:

```
ln -s /<stuff after Macintosh HD in the info view, separated by forward slashes> ~/Desktop
```

This will create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) in your user directory, which will make it look like the folder is there (so you can click it), but it will actually still be in the location you found it.

I am not aware of a way to actually changing the location. You might also just be fine with just creating a new folder called "Desktop" in your home directory, as [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304810/change-path-of-desktop) seems to indicate that that's what will be shown on your desktop then.

Comment: Because my Desktop folder in sidebar has the location "iCloud > Desktop", so I couldn't see "where" category in information. I want to make Desktop folder which has the location "Macintosh HD > Users > {username} > Desktop" in home directory.

Comment: @bolero Does right-clicking in your home folder and "Create new Folder" not work? Otherwise you could also try Terminal.app with the command `mkdir ~/Desktop` to create it from there.

Comment: Terminal has Desktop folder, but finder doesn't have it.

Comment: Now that I look at it, there is no Documents folder either.

Comment: Maybe the folders are just hidden in Finder?